# Android remove shadow of transparent navigation view

Tags: android, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have a transparent `NavigationView`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The toolbar is transparent because of this

```
android:background="@drawable/transparent"
```

I would like to keep the navigation icon but hide the shadow of the toolbar [image]

I try some solution found in SO but nothing work, i try to put the `app:elevation = 0`, but this make my toolbar icon disappears

This is how the navigation is implemented in Activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

EDIT: this is not a duplicate question as you can see in my question I already try the solution by using app:elevatation = 0, but this remove the navigation icon

Answer (score 0):

Try to put : `app:elevation="0"` in your `AppBarLayout`. 
This should work.

Comment: Yes this is working, but this hide my navigation icon